# absolutely positioned div is covering my content

Tags: html, css, responsive

[[image: here is what happens when the pic grows]]

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NIdav.jpg)i am making an introduction to my page by creating a profile picture positioned halfway the container, and the design is for mobile view.

the container that holds the pic and the name is positioned relative, while the pic is positioned absolute, the content which is contained below is positioned static by default(i think) and i made it to be 100% width to be able to center it.

Problem: the pic is covering the name below it, i tried to make a padding to position it below but when the pic grows bigger, it covers it again, i also tried media queries but this way i will make a break points every 100 px,: i don't think it is practical this way

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 350px;
  background-color: black;
}

.pic {
  position: absolute;
  width: 30%;
  top: -30%;
  left: 30%;
}

.content {
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 8rem;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="pic">img</div>
  <div class="content">name</div>
</div>
```

Comment: please add a screen shot  to your issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need any fancy absolute positioning for this:

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 350px;
  background-color: black;
  margin-top: 4rem;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
.pic {
  margin-top: -1.8rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <img src="//i.stack.imgur.com/fVW6p.png?s=48&g=1" class="pic">
    <div class="content">name</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, well, the absolute positioning takes the image out of page flow  and positions it relative to the nearest relatively-positioned ancestor, not bothering too much about other elements - so that is actually expected behavior. Is there any specific reason why you want your picture to be absolutely positioned? From what you have written, I'd say your best bet would be to go with flexbox as it's easiest to control placement.

Though, to be honest, you could probably go here with just removing absolute positioning, so it's again in the normal flow, and then centering your image div:

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 350px;
  background-color: black;
  padding: 1rem;
}
.pic {
  width: 30%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.content {
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 3rem;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="pic"><img src="https://picsum.photos/200/150" alt=""></div>
  <div class="content">name</div>
</div>
```

Comment: The reason i made it absolute is to make it halfway the container as showed on the screenshot, is there any other way to do that

Comment: Ah, I see, I was writing my reply before you added screenshot, and didn't exactly get your intentions :) In addition to alotropico's answer, you could also use here transform property on an image:
`transform: translateY(-50%);`

Answer (score 0):

Adding absolute positioning to the .content worked for me.